# How do I print a string in a box of astricks in python

Tags: python

```
def main():

    def read_txt():
        input_file = open("input.txt", "r") 
        global text
        text = input_file.readline()
        input_file.close()
        return text
    read_txt()

    def write_txt():
        output_file.write(text)
        output_file.close()
    write_txt()

main()
```

The content of input.txt is just a single line string with any length. I am trying to read the content of input.txt and write it to another file output.txt. But the string should be inside a box of asterisks that is no more than 50 characters and **the single line string should be divided into more than one line.** But the string from input.txt can be any length.
For example, if the content of input.txt is "I really love programming becuase it is fun! " then output.txt should look like something like this,

```
   ****************************************
   *                                      *
   *    I really love programming         *
   *    becuase it is fun!                *
   *                                      *
   *                                      *
   *                                      *
   *                                      *
   *                                      *
   *                                      *
   *                                      *
   ****************************************
```

So I really need help on making the box please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose you can use [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) library.

With it your code will be similar to this:

```py
import textwrap
# your code
    def read_txt():
        input_file = open("input.txt", "r") 
        global text
        text = input_file.readline()
        input_file.close()
        padding = 3  # 3 spaces from left and right
        max_line_length = 48 - padding * 2  # 48 because 50 - 2*asterisks
        lines = textwrap.wrap(text, max_line_length)
        wrapped_text = 50 * '*' + '\n'
        for line in lines:
            wrapped_text += '*{pad}{text:{width}}{pad}*\n'.format(text=line, pad=' '*padding, width=max_line_length)
        wrapped_text += 50 * '*'
        return wrapped_text
```

Comment: Are you saying I don't need to change anything for the write_txt function?

Comment: @Brook if you want save formatted text to file, then pass ```wrapped_text``` to your ```write_txt``` function.

Comment: Oh, ok I got it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Brook if this answer solves your problem, then mark it **Accepted**, so as not to distract other people to your question.

Comment: @Brook also it's better if you'll pass ```text``` variable to your functions instead of making it ```global```.